# Tensorflow wrapper which acts just like numpy (very close API)?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Does there exist a library/wrapper for Tensorflow which allows you to do everything you would do in numpy, with the same API/syntax? In other words, one could very nearly replace every `np.` with `tf.` and get a very near functionality?

Then, one could do some sleek stuff like this (I did this by inheriting tf.Variable):

```
a = Tens([[1, -2, 3]], name='a')
b = Tens([[2], [4], [-1]], name='b')

dot_product = a @ b
vector_sum = a + b.T

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init_op)

print(dot_product.eval())
print(vector_sum.eval())

>>> [[-9]]
>>> [[3 2 2]]
```

It would be cool to be able to do practically a drop-in replacement for a numpy script and get all the joys of TF processing.

If this also appeals to you, let me know in the comments.

Comment: No such library exists that I know of.  A numpy expression like **x + y** does computation, where as a tensorflow expression like **x + y** defines a graph, which is why you need the **vector_sum.eval()** line.  Todays implementation of both are different enough that even if it did exist it would be a *best effort* and only partial implementation.  Hopefully in 20 years when GPU computation is applied to everything then we'll be there.  Just think of **multi-threaded** applications and how long we've had them and still there are so many special code calls to leverage that tech.

Comment: Good point. But that's exactly why I think this is a cool idea. I realize that the definition of "+" in this case is a little different, but I like to imagine the graph session as just like lazy evaluation.

Comment: Come to think of it, writing a gradient function (or leveraging tensorflows) would be easy enough.  The heavy lifting of GPU optimization that TF does would be challenging to do though.  But, if you were okay with a nonoptomized cpu-only version... Sure, it's totally possible.

Comment: It doesn't exist, but it would be cool to have.

Comment: @wontonimo I've been toying around with this idea, and definitely find that the GPU I/O bottlenecks for a lot of problems. GPU works great for NN, because you load a whole minibatch into GRAM, but for things like datasets with zillions of data points but a simple process graph, not so much. But, the scalability and multithreading features of TF make this super useful. I could use Dask, but I find Dask unweildy at smaller scales.